# How can I add an xml declaration when serializing data using quick_xml and serde?

Tags: xml, rust, serde

I am trying to use the serde functionality of quick_xml to serialize and deserialize between xml and rust. A minimal example shown below works well. However when I serialize back into xml I no longer have the xml declaration, which makes sense as I don't have it as part of the rust struct.

```
#[derive(Default, PartialEq, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename = "response", default)]
pub struct Response {
    pub protocol: String,
    pub server: String,
}
```

Deserialisation from this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response protocol="3.0" server="prod">
</response>
```

Serialisation looks like this:

```
<response protocol="3.0" server="prod">
</response>
```

My question is what is the best way to include the declaration when serializing back into xml. There seems to be an `Event::Decl` which handles this but I'm not sure of usage through serde. Should the declaration be a part of my Rust structure or could I leave it out and handle it seperately?

Comment: I was thinking you could use [`write_pi_content`](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/latest/quick_xml/struct.ElementWriter.html#method.write_pi_content) for that, but I was only able to generate `<xml><?version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?></xml>` with that. In any case, you'd need direct access to  the writer (see the examples [here](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/latest/quick_xml/se/struct.Serializer.html#)) for that, in which case you can also just write the xml declaration as a bunch of bytes, outside of serialization: `writer.inner().write_all(b"<?xml …?>\n");`

Comment: Addendum: I guess you could use `writer.write_event(Event::PI(BytesText::from_escaped_str("xml …")))`, but it doesn't have much advantage over just writing the bytes directly.